# Why does my site show the correct front-page when you arrive at the site, but not when you click 'home'?

Tags: frontpage, menus

I have a website ([derbyskillbuild.org.uk](http://derbyskillbuild.org.uk)) and the 'home' button leads to a diffent page than the 'front-page':

- When you arrive at my website, it displays the correct front-page.php with the loop on the right hand side.
- When you click 'home' in the navigation, a standard page is displayed without the loop.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackexchange. When asking a question please try to be as specific in your question as possible. Try describing what you want to know – also using screenshots or wireframes is ok – but please avoid forcing others to ckick on a link to understand your question. Questions like "How can I do this?" are usually not very likely to get a lot of attention from the community.

That said – I did click the link – and I see two pages: the "home" page and the *front–page*.

If you want the "home" button to direct users to your *front–page*, you can do this in Wordpress's admin interface under `Appearance > Menus`. Basically there  are various ways to to this – here's two approaches, leading to the same ersult: Depending on how your site is / your menus are configures I would either make the "*home*" button link to "/" manually, or add a new custom button "home" (linking to "/") and remove the old one (linking to "/home").